# How to install an emacs lisp patch in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, emacs

I ran into a problem with an Emacs Lisp function, and I got a patch from the developer.  I'm running Debian Linux and the file to be patched does not even exist on my system.  (The patch is for `tex-mode.el` and I have only `tex-mode.el.gz` and `tex-mode.elc`.)  I would prefer *not* to stomp all over the Debian distribution code in `/usr/share/emacs`.  Is there a way for me to install the patched `tex-mode.el` in my home directory so that it takes priority over the version in the system directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy `tex-mode.el.gz` to your home directory (say in `.emacs.d`) and then `gunzip` it, apply the patch, and byte compile it.  Of course the directory where you put it has to be in your `load-path`, or you could just add `(load "/path/to/new/tex-mode.el")` to your `.emacs` which would ensure you don't get the old version.

Comment: You can even do this from Emacs: open `tex-mode.el.gz` and Emacs will decompress it on the fly.  Save a copy with `C-x C-w`, and as long as the new file name doesn't end with `.gz`, it will be saved uncompressed.